# Object update is not committed to realm when doing it within a write transaction

Tags: android, android-studio, realm

First of all sorry for my english.

I've been working with android a few months. I'm developing an app that will be used to check the articles within a rute are downloaded from the truck when arrives at the destinantion. When the destination is completed is marked as complete.

The first time I load the rute, mark the articles downloaded and export the rute to the database all works fine. My problem comes if I try to load the same rute again, because i want to mark the destination as complete because all of it's articles where downloaded before but the destination is not updated. The code that is not working is "seccion.setXcompleta(true);"

```
private void actualizarDestinos(ArrayList<String> secs) {
        for (int i = 0; i < secs.size(); i++) {
            RealmResults<CabeceraPedido> cabeceraPedidos = realm.where(CabeceraPedido.class).equalTo("xpv_destino", secs.get(i)).findAll();
            if (!cabeceraPedidos.isEmpty()) {
                ArrayList<Integer> numdoc_ids = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < cabeceraPedidos.size(); j++) {
                    for (int c = 0; c < cabeceraPedidos.size(); c++) {
                        numdoc_ids.add(cabeceraPedidos.get(c).getXnumdoc_id());
                    }

                    RealmResults<LineaPedido> lineasPedido = realm.where(LineaPedido.class).in("xnumdoc_id", numdoc_ids.toArray(new Integer[0])).findAll();
                    Seccion seccion = realm.where(Seccion.class).equalTo("xseccion_id", cabeceraPedidos.get(j).getXpv_destino()).findFirst();
                    if (lineasPedido.isEmpty()) {
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        seccion.setXcompleta(true);
                        cabeceraPedidos.get(j).setxDescargaCompleta(true);
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(seccion);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
                    } else {
                        realm.beginTransaction();
                        seccion.setXcompleta(false);
                        cabeceraPedidos.get(j).setxDescargaCompleta(false);
                        realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(seccion);
                        realm.commitTransaction();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

As is said, when I do it the first time I load the rute the destination is marked as complete when all the articles are dowloaded from the truck.

**UPDATE**

"Seccion" is a class that extends RealmObject. It is used to store the destinations on a rute. By default, when the rute is loaded the section is not complete because any of the articles contained on it are downloaded.

```
public class Seccion extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private String xseccion_id;
    private String xnombre;
    private String xgrupo_des;
    private String xlocal_act;
    private String xclave;
    private boolean xactual;
    private boolean xcompleta;

    public Seccion() {

    }

    public Seccion(String xseccion_id, String xnombre, String xgrupo_des, String xlocal_act, String xclave, boolean xactual) {
        this.xseccion_id = xseccion_id;
        this.xnombre = xnombre;
        this.xgrupo_des = xgrupo_des;
        this.xlocal_act = xlocal_act;
        this.xclave = xclave;
        this.xactual = xactual;
        this.xcompleta = false;
    }
}
```

Every section have one or more order headers (`cabeceraPedido`), and every order header have one or more order lines (`lineasPedido`). The image below shows one destination with four order headers (the order headers are not shown directly) with some order lines.

[Destination section loaded incomplete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d6NQq.png)

When all the articles from an order header are downloaded is checked as completed with `cabeceraPedidos.get(j).setxDescargaCompleta(true)`, and when all the order headers are checked as completed the section is also checked as completed `seccion.setXcompleta(true)`. At the UI the destination is highligthed in green.

[Destination section checked as complete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjgZx.png)

At this point, on realm every order header and section are checked as complete. Now I export (`EXPORTAR` button) the data to database.

Now is when my problem comes. I load the same rute again, with the same destination and order headers but the order lines are not loaded because the articles where downloaded before. Every order header are checked as completed in `actualizarDestinos` method on the if clause but not the section, so i cannot highlight it on green in my recyclerview.

Comment: performing some troubleshooting may reveal the issue. I suggest adding a breakpoint here `RealmResults<LineaPedido>` then step through the code. Ensure both `lineasPedido` and `succion` is populated. Then continue stepping through the code to see which part of the `if` block is called. Keep in mind that a Realm transaction will either pass or fail. If anything within the transaction fails, all of it will fail. So the issue could be this `cabeceraPedidos.get(j)` for example.

Comment: `lineasPedido` and `seccion` are always populated because I always have `cabeceraPedidos` populated. It may happen that `lineasPedido` is empty but it is fine to enter through the if clause. The problem is that `seccion.setXcompleta(true)` is not updated in the realm object but instead `cabeceraPedidos.get(j).setxDescargaCompleta(true)` is updated and confirmed.

Comment: The problem is that as-is, there's nothing wrong with your code. However, there's a lot of missing information; we don't know what `Seccion` is or does, we don't know what `.setXcompleta(true);` does or what `.get(j).setxDescargaCompleta` does. It's going to be difficult to help much more without that information in the question. Those realm functions are also within a loop so it's possible that during the loop the same nodes are being updated with true/false/true to it appears it's not changing when it is.

Comment: I updated the question trying to explain the functionality and the workflow.

Comment: Do some troubleshooting by examining the raw data using Realm Studio. In the first `if` block, after this line `realm.commitTransaction();` add a placeholder `print` and put a breakpoint on that line. Then add a breakpoint here `Seccion seccion = realm.where`. Open your Realm file with Realm Studio. You're going to inspect the object you think is being modified before, and then after the write transaction. Run your app. It will break at the first break; inspect those objects properties (false). Continue the app to the next breakpoint. Inspect the objects again which should be true.

Comment: I solved my problem. It was my mistake. Instead of look at the number of order lines, now I check the number of units downloaded from every order line contained in every order header. If the number of units it is 0, I mark the order header as complete, and when all of the order headers are complete, also mark the section as complete.

By the way, thanks for your help @Jay